# Extract Latest List Items & Update Another Summary List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am using List to track weekly status of a few projects, how can I develop auto extract only latest projects status (not only one project) to another executive summary list, which only shows latest progress of the projects, whenever change made?

Comment: Can you use Power Automate (MS Flow)? When an item is changed/updated in [Projects] list, update the Summary list accordingly using Power Automate.

Comment: Hi Matiur Rahman, it will be helpful if there is specific snapshot or references on Power Automate. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the list structures (Projects and Summary) with sample data? And what pieces of info from Projects to be copied to Summary and at what circumstances (pseudo code)?